# WhereIn on serialized base64 encoded MySql column value in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, serialization, eloquent

I have a **serialized base64 encoded column** in MySQL table. 
whenever I store a value in it, I store it this way:

```
$category_id = base64_encode(serialize($request->category_id));
```

And Whenever I want to retrieve its value to normal I use below code in my model:

```
 public function getCategoryIdAttribute($value)
    {
        return unserialize(base64_decode($value));
    }
```

The Problem is how can I write an eloquent query to check values of this column?

let's assume after **unserializing and decoding** in the database I have: `category_id : [1, 5, 3, 9]`,

And cat_id variable is: `$cat_id = [3];` or `$cat_id = [1, 9];`

how should I write my query to be able to check if my variable is in the category_id array?

I mean something like:

```
Seat::WhereIn('category_id', $cat_id);
```

Should I write my query this way:

```
Seat::WhereIn('category_id', base64_encode(serialize($cat_id)));
```

Comment: Ah, I can see why you serialize and encoded the value, but now you run into the reason why you shouldn't have done that. You should (almost) always use singular values in a database if you want to use queries on those values. I suggest you normalize you database now, because this will only get worse. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization (don't be scared by the very formal approach to this topic, it's not as difficult as it might seem at first).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Really? so it's a bad idea from the first place?

Comment: Yes, a very bad idea, just don't do it. Make a separate table called 'catagories-???' containing two columns, one for the catagory id and another for the id of the row in the table the encoded catagory id is in now. This is called a 'link-table', it links the catagories to your table.

Comment: Also the performance of this is terrible

Comment: Just to echo what @KIKOSoftware said, this is something I would strongly advise against. You will be unable to query individual category IDs if you store it like that. The best way to approach this is to normalise it and set up a many to many relationship with a pivot table. An alternative approach, if your database supports it is to use a JSON column type. You would be able to store multiple IDs in a single column and query them individually but only if your database supports it. Normalisation would be the best way to go though.

Comment: @Jonathon can you explain more about the second approach? I mean If I store it as json how am i able to query it?

Comment: If your database supports it (MySQL 5.7.8 and above) there's a `JSON` column type. That allows your to store multiple values in a single column using `JSON` format and use a special syntax to query them. See [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql) for a tutorial. Again, I would like to strongly urge you to go down the normalisation route. It's definitely the recommended approach for your particular problem. Laravel has built in support for it as well. All you'd need to do is set up a pivot table and some relations to be able to use it.

Comment: @Jonathon so if the relations are the best approach and has better performance for this problem then I'll switch it to relation mode.

Comment: Property accessors and mutators are on the model but `whereIn` is in the query builder. So you need to base64 encode and serialise in when using the query builder as well. Also you seem to be serializing and base64 encoding an identifier which is generally a number (I hope). What is the actual benefit of doing this?